# Is it possible to implement Google Enhanced Ecommerce using @nuxtjs/google-analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js, enhanced-ecommerce

I have web-application which has been implemented on Nuxt.js. I have connected Google Analytics to it, but there were nothing I was needed.

So, I have read about Google Enhanced Ecommerce and want to connect it to my app.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#implementation), I found what I actually want to do, but I have no idea on how can I do it on Nuxt.js.

For example:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (number).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});
```

And as you can see, this is just pure JS, definitely not what I need. As I said, `@nuxtjs/google-analytics` has no such functionality. Iе has only page, event, screen and timings trackers, but this is not what I am looking for.

**So, I'll ask this way: how can I implement code above (Enhanced Ecommerce) using `Nuxt.js`?**

If someone has already done this and integrated Enhanced Ecommerce into Nuxt.js apps, how did you do that? Or is it still possible to do such things with `@nuxtjs/google-analytics`?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [@nuxtjs/google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-analytics) is using [vue-analytics](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics), which *does* support ecommerce.  We were using it for quite a while before switching to just regular GTM (mostly due to vue-gtag being too new at the time).

Just a note from the repo:

> ⚠️ Sorry but vue-analytics is not longer maintained. I would suggest you to switch to [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag). With love, the guy who made the package.

Anyways, vue-analytics provides an example of how to use ecommerce [here](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/master/docs/ecommerce.md#usage).

First, you need to enable it in your nuxt config:

```
export default {
  googleAnalytics: {
    id: 'UA-XXX-X',
    ecommerce: {
      enabled: true,
      enhanced: true // enables enhanced ecommerce
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can call it like so in your components or Vuex modules:

```
this.$ga.ecommerce.addItem({
  id: '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  name: 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  sku: 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  category: 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  price: '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  quantity: '1'                   // Quantity.
})
```

See [here](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/c8841d42e265f4c6aa350db354f701c75284caca/src/lib/ecommerce.js#L8) for the full list of method names you can use on `$ga`.